Electron store ES6 modular import, cannot initialise store object
I'm trying to use electron-store package to store values in a vue + electron application.
I've followed the examples given by the author here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-store.
But im getting error when running the app, whenever. store seems to be undefined.
electron main.js
import Store from "electron-store";
const store = new Store();

ipcMain.on("electronStore", (event, args) => {
    if (args.commandStr === "getElectronStore") {
        console.log(store);
        console.log(new Store())
        console.log(store.get(args.key));
        mainWindow.webContents.send("electronStore", store.get(args.key));
    }
    else if (args.commandStr === "setElectronStore") {
        store.set(args.key, args.value);
    }
});


my app is modular, so ive made sure all my packages are imported using ESM format:
package.json:
  "type": "module",

any idea whats wrong with this? how do i initialize electron store properly ?

import Store from "electron-store";
Store.initRenderer();
const electronStorage = new Store();

Dont forget to initialize the storage before instantiating a new storage object. All i had to do was add
Store.initRenderer();

and it all works now.
